# New dexterity content type is not visible from the "add link" dialogue

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have made a new dexterity content type, but it is not visible from the "add link" dialogue.
How can I make my content type show up in this link box?

Comment: You meant: from the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add your content type to the "Linkable Objects". You can do that TTW in "TinyMCE Settings" or programatically in a tinymce.xml file as part of your install profile. (Take a look at the export of your Product.TinyMCE settings in portal_setup.)